# regex deal with double backslash

Tags: python, regex

Ths string is `G:\\one\\two\\three.htm` , the result I want is `G/one/two/three.htm` ,how can I get the desired  result  with python and regex ?
I have tried `re.sub('\\\\\\\\', '/', string)` , it worked but left `:` . I don't want to do with regex again to remove `:` . who can help me with the above question ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is @Matthias's answer, adapted to Python:

```
In [6]: re.sub(r':?\\+', '/', r'G:\\one\\two\\three.htm')
Out[6]: 'G/one/two/three.htm'
```

Note the regex pattern is `r':?\\+'`, not `':?\\+'`.

The `r` tells Python that what follows is a raw string.

Python interprets `':?\\+'` as a string with one backslash:

```
In [7]: list(':?\\+')
Out[7]: [':', '?', '\\', '+']
```

Using `list`, as above, allows you to see the individual characters in the string. `'\\'` is a Python string consisting of one backslash.

Python interprets `r':?\\+'` as a string with two backslashes:

```
In [8]: list(r':?\\+')
Out[8]: [':', '?', '\\', '\\', '+']
```

---

The reason why `':?\\\\\\\\'` worked for you is because Python interprets it as a string with four backslashes:

```
In [9]: list(':?\\\\\\\\')
Out[9]: [':', '?', '\\', '\\', '\\', '\\']
```

The regex engine then interprets every two backslashes as a pattern matching one literal backslash. So regex interprets the four backslashes as a pattern which matches two literal backslashes.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing python, I would suggest

```
re.sub(':?\\+', '/', string)
```

Comment: **+1** ... As log as it's okay to convert `G:\\foo:\\bar` to `G/foo/bar`, this looks good to me.

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't need regular expressions here:

```
>>> s = r"G:\\one\\two\\three.htm"
>>> print s
G:\\one\\two\\three.htm
>>> s.replace(r"\\","/")
'G:/one/two/three.htm'
>>> s.replace(r"\\","/").replace(":","",1)
'G/one/two/three.htm'
```

Note that I used a "raw string" (`r` before the `"`) so that I didn't have to escape all the backslashes, and the `count` option to `replace` to leave in any colons beyond the first in case they were part of a filename.

[I have to admit I'm a little surprised that `G/one/two/three.htm` is really what you want, though.]

Comment: This fails for UNC paths, such as \\\\myServer\\myDir\\mySubDir\\